# Keep div shown after submitting form using jQuery in MODx Evo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modx, formit

I have a form that is hidden when first loading this [page](https://www.outerbankslaw.com/home-lead-generation-round-1.html)

Once user clicks the chevron down below "CONTACT US AND TELL US ABOUT YOUR CASE" the form appears.

Once eform submits, the form becomes hidden again

```
<div class="describe" style="display: none;">
```

and validation messages are not viewable unless the chevron is clicked again as seen here:

https://share.getcloudapp.com/RBuXmEvE

I'm using

```
<button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.submit();">Submit</button>
```

to submit the form.

Should I call another javascript function that runs onclick as well as the code to display the form?

I believe that the javascript code currently being used to show and hide the form is here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

          $('.case > a').click(function(){
           $('.describe').slideToggle();  
              $(this).toggleClass('active');
          });

     });    
  </script>
```

Or should I attempt to show the form in a MODx snippet (which is just PHP code)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a snippet to determine if the form is submitted and use that result to display (or not) your element. I suggest using an [Extra named FormIt](https://modx.com/extras/package/formit) for creating forms on your website ([FormIt documentation](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/extras/formit)).